# Interact with .db file

Tags: database, sqlite

I searched on several forums for the answer to my question but I didn't find a concrete answer.

I ask you which is the best language to interact with a file .db.
At present, I try to use the VBS but I am not sure whether it is the simplest language for it.

My purpose being to be able to look in a database if a variable is there, and if it is not there, my program adds it to the database in a new line.

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my low level in english.

Edit :

I imagine a code like that :

```
Dim objConn, following, txtSQL

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=C:\Users\leyh\Downloads\test.db"

txtSQL = "SELECT Name FROM Test WHERE key = " & following
While MacroFollows
    If followexisting = 0 Then
        txtSQL = "INSERT INTO Test (Name) VALUES"
        txtSQL = txtSQL & "('" & following & "')"
    Else
        DoNothing
    End If
Loop

objConn.Close
```

But my problem is to "interact" with the database in real time, I explain :

My VBS program is a macro which follows automatically people on a social network, my aim is to write in my database people that I followed, line per line.

Comment: a database does not contain any variables. just sets of data (datasets) stored in tables. maby some stored procedures but no variables. maby you intent is to search for a table containing a special values

Comment: Oups, sorry for that.
I wanted to say a variable in my program VBS which corresponds to a value in my table.

Comment: VBS (meaning Visual Basic Script) or VB.NET (= Visual Basic .NET (object orientetd programming language))?

Comment: Since every (modern) programming language supports querying a databse, you should specify your question

Comment: But as I read your question, you are searching for the easiest way to query a database and check if there is a table containg a specific value in one of it's columns.

Comment: VBS = Visual Basic Script.
Yes exactly. In VBS I can use easily SQL queries so I chose it but I'm not an expert in VBS.

Comment: ok so if you want to solve it in VBS, then just ask google for some result **vbs querying db file**. otherwise, tell us your existing code so we can help you to improve it

Comment: Ok thanks. I will edit my post with my existing code.